# Server side rendering and client side scripts scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, server-side-rendering

I'm working on an old project that uses servers side rendering with express and handlebars. Some templates have a script tag with some client-side code that is only used inside that same template. The problem is this code has a global scope, and often variable names get in conflict.

My question is, has anyone created some way of handling this by making scripts scoped?

Comment: "has anyone created some way of handling this by making scripts scoped?" - yes, JavaScript Modules.

Comment: Can you please provide some code you have?